# Java editor of Web Dynpro is not found in SAP NWDS

Tags: java, netweaver, webdynpro

I moved my Web Dynpro from NWDI 7.0 to 7.3, and since then I can't open Java editor for my Web Dynpro program in 7.3 release. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to download the last version of SAP Netweaver. The editor is already provided. If you have any problem you can contact the SAP support.

Answer (score 0):

The *Java Editor* of a Web Dynpro view sometimes cannot be opened when there are errors in the view.

Please check the eclipse views "Problems" or "Markers" and try to fix all errors that can be fixed from the *View Editor*. Also expand all subnodes of the view context and look for errors (red x) there.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes affected on webdynpro from version 7.0 to 7.3, for example interface controller is not longer existing.

You should use migration wizzard, that would help you to change a 7.0 dc project configuration, to 7.3

You can check that web on sap page explaining that problems.

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/8061e964-2036-2e10-ee9d-ef21d174fdd9?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true

If you have followed that steps and you cant open the view some errors should be prompted on problems, some of they are blocking, so it can not be related directly with the view.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can do before ringing the alarm bells:

1. As Tobias kindly proposed, if errors are present in View or Component Controller, sometimes this view/controller cannot be opened in editor. The most evident action here is to automatically fix (Quick Fix) the errors which are listed in *Problems* tab.
2. If they cannot be fixed automatically, then you should understand what is the error and fix it manually. However, even fixed, NWDS doesn't always properly treat the environment (filesystem sync is often bad) and cannot understand the error had been fixed already. In this case **Rebuild project** and **Repair** functions often help. They can be called by context menu on WD-project.
3. The last (but not least!) point you should check before development is the compatibility of version between NWDS and NWDI. As stated in this blog:

> the major release of 
>   - NWDS 
>   - Local AS (optional but if it is used it also has to match regarding its version) 
>   - Track 
>   - RunTime Systems (further referred as RTSs) 
>   **should always match**.

7.4 [is an exclusion](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1791485) from this rule.
Moreover, NWDS also has to match both Release and SP **especially when it comes to modeling tools like WebDynpro**. More about these [in this note](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/718949)
so I strongly recommend you to check all versions and bring them into compliance if they are still not. 
Maybe these resources about [NWDI](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/48/2f8c4856ab58d5e10000000a421937/content.htm?frameset=/en/48/257b2042ac539ae10000000a421937/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/48/257a6542ac539ae10000000a421937/plain.htm&node_id=3) and [Webdyn Pro](http://scn.sap.com/community/web-dynpro-java/blog/2013/02/22/migration-of-web-dynpro-java-dcs-from-70-to-731-stepwise-procedure-and-troubleshooting) migrating will help you too.